# How to get X,Y,Z rotations of vertices on a sphere at the origin?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, rotation, trigonometry

Hey, I have a sphere in my game world and i would like to place a plane at each vertex on this sphere for debugging purposes. The planes should be orientated so that they lie flat against the sphere (perpendicular to the normals). The sphere is located at the origin, so all the vertices are relative to that.

If my thinking is correct, i should be able to do this using the positions of the vertices and some simple trigonometry. I have tried a few combinations but have had no joy yet. I would greatly appreciate some help on this. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
float xRot = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(sinf(vertex.x/PLANET_RADIUS));
float yRot = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(cosf(vertex.y/PLANET_RADIUS));
glRotatef(xRot, 1.0, 0, 0);
glRotatef(yRot, 0, 1.0, 0);
```

Comment: So... what happens when you try this code? What's the result?

Comment: Well, its kinda hard to explain, but the planes all seem to be aligned in roughly the same orientation. As i say i have tried various combinations of the sin/cos and different axis of rotations, but none of them seem to give the desired result

Comment: you don't understand rotations/sine/cosine functions. I suggest to get a trigonometry book. You need to use asin and acos to extract rotations, and you'll have to compute z component of the vertex. Depending on where initial position of the object is located, xRot will be asinf(vertex.y/PLANET_RADIUS), and yRot will be acosf(vertex.x / sqrtf(vertex.x*vertex.x + vertex.z*vertex.z)). If rotation goes in wrong direction, you'll have to add - to it.